# How to add function in all links through jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xmlhttprequest

I am using following function to load the page. I have loads of links and can't add to all links.

```
function LoadPage(url) {
  $("#canvas").load(url);
}
```

I want a function which will get all `<a>` tags `href` value and add this function to all links just like following:

```
var oP  = document.getElementsByTagName("a"),
    ctr = 0
;

while(ctr < oP.length) {
  var oldHref = document.getElementsByTagName("a")[ctr].href;

  document.getElementsByTagName("a")[ctr].href = "javascript:loadPage('" + oldHref + "');";
  ctr++;
}
```

I want to add to all links but not to "INDEX.HTML".

Comment: Two comments on the regular Javascript code you provided: 1. You already have `document.getElementsByTagName("a")` stored into `oP`, calling it again inside your `while` loop is extra and unnecessary processing. 2. Iterating other a collection of elements is generally done with a `for` loop, not a `while` loop, since you know the required number of iterations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
// select all links
$('a')
  // check that the pathname component of href doesn't end with "/index.html"
  .filter(function() {
    return !this.href.pathname.match( /\/index\.html$/ );
    // // or you may want to filter out "/index.html" AND "/", e.g.:
    // return !this.href.pathname.match( /\/(index\.html)?$/i )
  }) 
  // add a click event handler that calls LoadPage and prevents following the link
  .click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    LoadPage(this.href);
  });
```

Since you're dynamically loading sections of the page, you'll need to set up event delegation instead. Exactly how you go about doing this depends on the version of jQuery you're using, but you'll be using either the [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) (jQuery 1.7+) or [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) (prior to jQuery 1.7) functions. The `.on()` example would look something like this:

```
$('body').on('click', 'a', function(e) {
    if(!this.href.pathname.match( /\/index\.html$/ )) {
        e.preventDefault();
        LoadPage(this.href);
    }
});
```

Comment: its loading the page but it doesnt convert the links of newly loaded page. What i should do for newly loaded pages?

Comment: include that script in the newly loaded page too.

Comment: @danny I completely overlooked that - since you're dynamically loading content, event delegation is the way to go. I've updated my answer to include the code using `.on()` - if you're using a version of jQuery prior to 1.7, you'll need to use `.delegate()` instead; the differences in syntax are relatively minor, so you should be able to convert if needed by reading the sections of the documentation that have been linked.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist $('body').on is undefined what that means?

Comment: @danny More than likely it means you're using a version of jQuery prior to 1.7, which wouldn't have the `.on()` function. Use `.delegate()` instead; there's a minor syntax change from the `.on()` code you'll need to make - read the documentation for the two functions to find out what that is.

Answer (score 0):

In reply to your question about converting links on the newly-loaded page, [`$.load()` takes a second argument](http://api.jquery.com/load/#callback-function) for a callback function which you can use to apply a function like @AnthonyGrist's to the new content, e.g.:

```
function loadPage( url ) {
  // add a callback to $.load() to be executed for the next content
  $("#canvas").load( url, function() { convertLinks( this ); } );
}

function convertLinks( context ) {
  // select all links in the given context
  $( 'a', context )
    // check that the pathname component of href doesn't end with "/index.html"
    .filter(function() {
      return !this.href.pathname.match( /\/index\.html$/ );
      // // or you may want to filter out "/index.html" AND "/", e.g.:
      // return !this.href.pathname.match( /\/(index\.html)?$/i )
    }) 
    // add a click event handler that calls LoadPage and prevents following the link
    .click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      loadPage( this.href );
    })
  ;
}

// call convertLinks on the whole document on initial page load
$( function() { convertLinks( document ); } );
```

Using `.on()` is a reasonable solution as well.

Comment: @Jorden your code is giving me error of missing }. can you please recheck?

Comment: @danny Fixed. It was on the third line. Generally code in Stack Overflow answers isn't meant to be copied-and-pasted, but to be understood and implemented on your own once you understand it. ;)